# Solving second order partial differential equation

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

I' trying to solve this differential equation:

$$y^2 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial y^2} - 2xy \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x \partial y} + x^2 \frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial x^2} + 2y \frac{\partial  u}{\partial y} = 0$$

I've done following substitution: $$s = xy, \ \ t= y , \ \ u(x,y) = v(s, t)$$

and as a result I have
$$t ^2 v _{t t} + 2s v_s + t v_t = 0$$ which I do not know how to solve.

Could you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you can try a different substitution such as $z=log(x)$ and $t=log(y)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed,
$
r=\ln y,\;s=\ln x
$
results in
$
(\partial _{r}-\partial _{s})(\partial _{r}-\partial _{s}+1)u=0
$
One obvious solution is
$
u=u(s+r)
$.
I leave it you to find the second.